# DBMS 2NF and 3NF

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

Given
R(a, b, c, d, e, p, w)
two keys: (b, c, d) and (p).

```
F ={
{b,c,d} -> {a,e,p,w}, 
p -> {a, b, c, d, e, w},
w -> c
}.
```

Is R in the 3rd normal form?

R(a,b,c,d,e) and a set of FD

```
F={ 
Fdl: {a,b} -> {c,d,e}
Fd2: c -> {a,b,d,e}
Fd3: e-> a
```

}

Keys for R: {a,b} and {c}.

Is R in 2nd normal form?

I know that in 2NF there must not be any partial dependency of any column on primary key, as well as, in 3NF every non-prime attribute of table must be dependent on primary key.

But I don't get these example from the book.

Comment: Both examples have three candidate keys.

Comment: 2NF means that every non-prime attribute must be dependent on the whole of every candidate key, not on part of *any* candidate key. Your definition of 3NF also needs some work.

Comment: You can't answer questions if you don't know what the words mean. So: what is a "(candidate) key"? PS What is your textbook?

Comment: The normal forms are all defined with respect to *every* candidate key, not just with respect to the one primary key.

Answer (score 0):

> Is R in the 3rd normal form?

No, R is not in 3NF as in 3NF we have two main properties: that if `X->A` then either X should be a super key or A should be a prime attribute. In FD3 `w->c` does not have these properties.

> Is R in 2nd normal form?

Yes it is in 2NF, as in the RHS of the FDs the prime attributes are present.